# Can't scale subplot y-axis in plotly with plotly_reasampler registered

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python, graph-visualization

I have the problem that somehow, if I use predict-idlab's awesome [plotly_resampler](https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler) package for plotting large datasets with plotly, I can't properly scale the y-axis of all subplots in a figure. Consider the following code

```py
from plotly_resampler import register_plotly_resampler, unregister_plotly_resampler
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

register_plotly_resampler(mode="auto", default_n_shown_samples=10000)

channels = [([1,2,3],[-10, 0, 10]), ([1,2,3], [5,4,0])]
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(channels), cols=1, subplot_titles=['subplot1', 'subplot2'], shared_xaxes=True)
for j, channel in enumerate(channels):
    x = channel[0]
    y = channel[1]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(x=x, y=y), row=j+1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text='x', row=j+1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='y', range=[-1.25, 1.25], row=j+1, col=1)
fig.update_layout(title_text='Plot Title')
display(fig)
        
unregister_plotly_resampler()
```

This results in the following plot:
[image]

So as can be seen the y-axis of the first subfigure is not scaled to the desired range. However, if I remove the `register/unregister_plotly_resampler()` lines, everything works like a charm:

[image]

What's the matter here?

EDIT=========================

I found a workaround:
If the y-axis is formatted with `fig.update_yaxes(range = [-1.5,1.5])` or `fig.update(layout_yaxis_range = [-1.5,1.5])` **before** running `register_plotly_resampler()`, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the meantime we [fixed](https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler/pull/126) the [known bug](https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler/issues/119) and made a [new release](https://pypi.org/project/plotly-resampler/).

Installing any plotly-resampler version >= 8.2.0, will result in expected behavior (similar to the behavior of plotly) - see illustration below

[example of scaling y-axis with plotly-resampler v8.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SKsf.png)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler/issues/119). The proposed workaround for the moment is to set autorange to False: `fig.update_xaxes(autorange=False)`. The following code snippet gives the desired result:

```py
from plotly_resampler import register_plotly_resampler, unregister_plotly_resampler
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# plot with plotly: with FigureResampler
register_plotly_resampler(mode="auto", default_n_shown_samples=10000)

channels = [([1,2,3],[-10, 0, 10]), ([1,2,3], [5,4,0])]
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(channels), cols=1, subplot_titles=['subplot1', 'subplot2'], shared_xaxes=True)
for j, channel in enumerate(channels):
    x = channel[0]
    y = channel[1]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(x=x, y=y), row=j+1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text='x', row=j+1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='y', range=[-1.25, 1.25], row=j+1, col=1)
fig.update_layout(title_text='Plot Title')
fig.update(layout_yaxis_range = [-1,1])
fig.update_yaxes(range = [-1.25,1.25], autorange=False)
display(fig)

unregister_plotly_resampler()
```